# When trying Cordova run browser getting error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHjxH.png)

When i try to use Cordova run browser code, its giving me error. I have attached the image above. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if thats an error that only occurs on browser. Did you test it on a device? For example, sometimes it gives error because browser doesn't support certain functionalities that only can be tested on a device. As i can see you can perfectly use the app or not? Need to add more detail.